# Qt Ubuntu SDK failed to parse plugins.qmltypes

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, mobile, arm

I have a basic App with QML Extension Library app setup with no changes except package identifiers and the similar (email, description, name).

Every time I open app/testApp.qml I get the following error:

```
Warnings while parsing QML type information of /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components:
Failed to parse '/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/plugins.qmltypes'.
Error: /var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/plugins.qmltypes:632:19: Expected string literal to contain 'Package/Name major.minor' or 'Name major.minor'.
/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/plugins.qmltypes:633:36: Expected array literal with only number literal members.
```

In addition, and this may be entirely different, when I click the Design button, the system doesn't work and there's an error partially hidden by the right menu. The error is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the qml plugin files required are not in the currently specified include directories listed on `[projectName].qmlproject` in the app project root directory.

I was testing on another project of a different type and I followed these instructions (the project was a QML project with a `.qmlproject` file).

It was near the bottom of the page, like this:

```
/* List of plugin directories passed to QML runtime */
    importPaths: [ "." ,"/usr/bin","/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml"]
```

I ran `find / -name *qml*` and found something that looked to be a suitable directory, with many items that had a good chance of being `qml` plugins, so I copied that directory, went to `[projectName].qmlproject` to the statement posted above and added the directory. The final importPaths statement looks like this:

```
/* List of plugin directories passed to QML runtime */
    importPaths: [ "." ,"/usr/bin","/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml","/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/" ]
```

After doing that, I could open the qml file in designer.

The effect also transferred to my other project, which does not have a `.qmlproject` file. I'm not sure why. I assume there's some kind of memory of the proper file, although I do not know the specifics.